# приложение Win.Form C# многопоточность

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть 3 потока и каждый из них добавляет данные в один и тот же список, который обрабатывается в 4 потоке .Корректна ли такая конструкция?

Comment: это не конструкция, это просто ваш текст. Тут нет ничего по сути. Объекты UI в формах доступны только из главного UI потока, то есть что бы вы с ними не делали, вы можете иметь доступ к ним только из одного потока. А вот сколько потоков будут получать данные элементам интерфейса до лампочки.

Comment: Корректна, почему нет. Только если список это UI элемент, то нужно будет применить `Invoke`

Comment: Клнструкция может и корректна, а вот корректна ли реализация - известно только тому человеку, который видел ваш код.

Comment: Добавлю, что если в списке важна упорядоченность, то просто писать из разных потоков - некорректно. Факторов корректности или некорректности очень много, напишите чуть более развернутый вопрос, если хотите конкретного ответа.